# T is number of testcases .N is size of array and k is number of right rotation of array.How to do this in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, rotation

I have used Scanner for array input.But Now I am getting Error:
Execution failed.
java.util.NoSuchElementException

Stack Trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
Input:

```
1
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

Output

```
4 5 1 2 3
```

MY Code is:

```
class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int T=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<T;i++) {
        String[] str=br.readLine().split(" ");
        int N=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        int K=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        int[] arr=new int[N];
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            arr[j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        int counter=0;

        if(counter!=K){
            int last=arr[N-1];
            for(j=N-1;j>0;j--){
                arr[j]=arr[j-1];
            }
            arr[0]=last;
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println();
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                System.out.print(arr[j]);
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: "1 2 3 4 5" is not a number it is a `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

`br.readLine()` reads one line at a time. If the line contains "1 2 3 4 5" it will throw the exception that you are getting. You need to split this string to an array that contains a number as String as its elements and then apply `parseInt()` to each of the elements.

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" "))
   .map(str -> Integer.parseInt(str)
   .collect(COllectors.toList())
```

Now you can process the elements.

Comment: Thanks for response Prashant.But when I am using scanner for input.It is giving error NoSuchElementException.

Comment: int[] arr=new int[N];
  for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
   arr[j]=sc.nextInt();
  }

Comment: Please update the question. That way everyone would be able to see the changes and probably help you. Do not add code to the comments.

Comment: I am not getting any exception. Its just that the code is not printing anything on the console. You need to check your algorithm.